# WPF DateTime in XAML. How to add days?

Tags: wpf, xaml, datetime

How do I add 10 days to the current date while specifying a date in XAML? I am using the below line for current date.The date needs to be today + 10 days

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}}>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the text need to be constantly refreshed? Or is it okay if it's set just once when the window is shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) for that, however you need to somehow refresh the binding as there are no update notifications by default.

Answer (score 2):

Your XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding NowPlusTen}" />
```

Your ViewModel (set as the DataContext of the text block or its parent:

```
  public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
          public ViewModel()
          {
          }

          public RefreshDate()
          {
                NowPlusTen = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(10);
                RaisePropertyChanged("NowPlusTen");

          }
          public DateTime NowPlusTen { get; private set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind to a ViewModel that provides the properly converted date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

> in the bracket of ToString() there is a format of date.