# Setting a static datetime in WPF/xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to blackout dates in my datetime picker control starting from day after today till datetime max value.

The below is the code:

```
    <Calendar.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="{x:Static System:DateTime.Today}"
 End="{x:Static System:DateTime.MaxValue}" />
    </Calendar.BlackoutDates>
```

As you could see, the above code will blackout dates starting from today, but I want the start date from tomorrow. Basically the question is, how can I set something like this:

`Start="{x:Static System:DateTime.Today.AddDays(1)}"`

Could you please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF DateTime in XAML. How to add days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739488/wpf-datetime-in-xaml-how-to-add-days)

Comment: Adrian: That is not true. That post talks about binding to viewmodel and the properties mentioned here are not dependency properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own static property for this.

```
  public static class DateTimeHelper
  {
    public static DateTime Tomorrow
    {
      get { return DateTime.Today.AddDays(1); }
    }
  }
```

.

```
  <CalendarDateRange Start="{x:Static app:DateTimeHelper.Tomorrow}"…
```

Comment: DataConverters are how I learned to add one day / modify a value for xaml, but this is way simpler.