# how do I set calendardaterange end to yesterday in xaml wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

Something like this 
but here it is giving an exception. can i have end tag to set the date to yesterday like given below so that my datepicker control black outs the dates until yesterday

```
<DatePicker BorderBrush="LightBlue" BorderThickness="1" 
  Name="dtTierValidTo"  IsEnabled="{Binding CanEdit}"
  DisplayDateStart="{Binding TierDealValidFromDate, Mode=OneWay}"   
  SelectedDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" 
  DisplayDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}" 
  Width="120" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/1500" End="7/22/2017"/>
    </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</DatePicker>
```

I want the end tag in calendarDateRange end to yesterday if i give like below

```
<CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/1500" End="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"/>
```

it is showing errors hence my requirement is that the end tag should take yesterday's date.

I want to blackout all the past dates. that means the user should only be able to select todays and future dates. Please help
[please click the link to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hp2yY.png)

It is giving the correct output if I pass the end date as below. but I want
the end date to be taken as yesterday instead of me manually entering the date

```
<DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
    <CalendarDateRange Start="1/1/1500" End="7/22/2017"/>
</DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
```

Comment: `Something like this`. Something like what?

Comment: `DatePicker.DisplayDateStart` is what you need

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: thq.. will surely do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below event worked for me.
in xaml -

```
<Calendar Name="calendar1" Loaded="calendar1_Loaded"/>
```

in xaml.cs page

```
 private void calendar1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
            DatePicker cal = sender as DatePicker;
            cal.BlackoutDates.AddDatesInPast();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

dtTierValidTo.DisplayDateStart = System.DateTime.Today.Date.AddDays(-1);
 dtTierValidTo.DisplayDateEnd = new DateTime(year, month, date);

Comment: Isn't `Today` better than `Now.Date` ?

Comment: I have done current date minus (1). It takes yesterday date.I hope @Padmaja Vudatha  expecting this @ Rafalon

Comment: Yes I know, I just wanted to say that `System.DateTime.Now.Date` is the same as `System.DateTime.Today` and the second is shorter

Comment: My one Include time also. Yours code take only date, correct?. ok thanks @Rafalon

Comment: As soon as you write `.Date` then you get rid of time... If you want to keep the time, then just write `System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);` without the `.Date`

Comment: @Saravanakumar I dont want the displaydateend, instead I want the user to select only today and future dates , so the dates until yesterday should be blackedout . kindly see the image provided

Answer (score 0):

### Edit :

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.calendar.blackoutdates(v=vs.110).aspx), you can add the range from the code-behind this way :

```
calendarWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(2009, 1, 2), new DateTime(2009, 1, 4)));
```

So nothing should stop you from doing this :

```
calendarWithBlackoutDates.BlackoutDates.Add(
    new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(1500, 1, 1), DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1));
```

You also might be interested in [Limiting the Range of Selectable Dates in a Calendar](https://wpf.2000things.com/2014/03/21/1034-limiting-the-range-of-selectable-dates-in-a-calendar/) using `DisplayDateStart` and/or `DisplayDateEnd` attribute for `Calendar` (and `DatePicker`).

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16463217/setting-a-static-datetime-in-wpf-xaml) you can find someone who had the same problem with `tomorrow` instead of `yesterday`, maybe it can help !

Comment: add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.CalendarBlackoutDatesCollection' threw an exception. both doesnt work for me as End property is taking only datecollections

Comment: first one neither works for me as it is saying Nested types are not supported:DateTime.Now

Comment: So it works for `SelectedDate` and `DisplayDate` but not for the blackout part ?

Comment: yes it is not working for CalendarDateRange End. Could you please help?

Comment: @PadmajaVudatha See my edit on how to add range to your blackout dates from code-behind

Comment: here this one i tried either .. but my datepicker control is not getting accessible from the xaml.cs

Comment: i tried like this dtTierValidTo.BlackOutDates.AddDaysInPast();

Comment: @PadmajaVudatha and it doesn't work with `.BlackoutDates.Add(new ....)` ? (notice `BlackoutDates` seems to be written with a small `o`)

Comment: that is because of a typo. I typed here instead of pasting the code,, please refer to this for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266619/how-can-i-access-datepicker-under-grid-under-datagridtemplate-column-in-my-xaml